# Cucumber find glue on include project but not in include JAR

Tags: cucumber, integration-testing, cucumber-java

I have a step definition file that I want to use in my test project. 
When my step definition file is placed inside an included project, all work fine. 
But if instead of include the project, I include the jar that correspond to the include project, cucumber don't find step definition class.

this is my annotation glue :

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "scenarii/connexion/", glue = {
        "cucumber.tests, "org.includeProject.cucumber"}
)
```

The Step definition classes in cucumber.tests are finds by cucumber, but those in org.includeProject.cucumber are not.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with earlier version (1.1) it was supported, but with latest version (1.2+) it is not supported or a defect.
It was working fine for me with 1.1.x (refer below ivy dependency) but not with versions there after.

```
    <dependency org="info.cukes" name="cucumber-java" rev="1.1.5" />
    <dependency org="info.cukes" name="cucumber-junit" rev="1.1.5"/>
    <dependency org="info.cukes" name="cucumber-html" rev="0.2.3"/>
```